# Guidelines for RDF terms for building RDF triples

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, vocabulary

I want to write down the following sentences in RDF Triple Notation:

> The hotel is located at Flowerstree 12, Vienna, Austria

```
urn:Hotel                   locatedAt   urn:locationOfHotel
urn:locationOfHotel:        hasNumber   12
urn:locationOfHotel:        hasStreet   Flowerstreet
urn:locationOfHotel:        hasCity     Vienna
urn:locationOfHotel:        hasCountrs  Austria
```

I have choosen the terms `locatedAt` and `hasNumber` via reading some tutorials.

I am searching for a RDF guideline which provides me a wide vocabulary. As example in [TEI](http://www.tei-c.org/index.xml) there are many rules, examples and guidelines I can follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many sources you could consult. [FOAF](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/) for example is a fairly popular one. [This website](http://richard.cyganiak.de/blog/2011/02/top-100-most-popular-rdf-namespace-prefixes/) has a collection of others ranked by popularity that you could consult. It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

You are, of course, also free to create your own, declaring `sameAs` relationships to any other ontologies that you like, or simply using them in yours. But beware of [the issues with sameAs](https://www.w3.org/2009/12/rdf-ws/papers/ws21).

Comment: perfect the link is what i have searched for, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at the [W3C RDF 1.1 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/) and [RDF 1.1 Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) text serialization for RDF, which is close to what you have started with.

Also Berners-Lee's [5-star Linked Open Data](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html) is a recognized source for architecting Semantic Web data repositories.  I mention this because of your use of URN's - which is just fine if there is no desire to dereference the URIs.  But if you need Web-based access and/or a linked open data approach, then the 5-Star criteria is good to follow.